# RabbitMQ publisher - multiple subscribers - how to set up in .Net?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

How to set up RabbitMQ clients/queues/exchanges for following scenario (in .Net)? I have one server (lets call it `server1`) which is running many services (`service1`, `service2`...) and multiple clients (`client1`, `client2`, `clientN`). I want messages generated by `server1`'s `service1` to be sent to all clients which are listening for messages from `service1`.

I managed to do that but I have one issue - apparently, although the message is received by client listening on exchange/queue `service1` and `AutoACK` is enabled, messages are not removed - when next one comes, old ones arrive again and clients `Received` events fires as many times as there were previous messages.

I need minimal example for server/producer (one sending messages) and example for clients which receive messages based on some routing key. If there is no clients listening for that specific routing key, never mind, message can be dropped. Routing key is known in advance by both server and client, so specific client "knows" that he wants to receive messages from `service2`.

Current setup is this:

Client code (this one listens all messages, that's the reason why the routing key is "#" - some clients have defined routing key - `service1` and so on.

```
servicesChannel = conn.CreateModel();
servicesChannel.ExchangeDeclare("services", ExchangeType.Fanout);

var queueName = servicesChannel.QueueDeclare().QueueName;
servicesChannel.QueueBind(queue: queueName, exchange: "services", routingKey: "#");
var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(servicesChannel);
consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
{
    // do bunch of stuff before
    log.Trace("Acknowledging message " + ea.DeliveryTag);
    // if we uncomment this, no more messages will arrive after 1st!
    //servicesChannel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);
}
servicesChannel.BasicConsume(queue: queueName, autoAck: true, consumer: consumer);
```

And server's code, pushing messages:

```
servicesChannel= conn.CreateModel();
servicesChannel.ExchangeDeclare("services", ExchangeType.Fanout);
...
string message = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, settings);
var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
servicesChannel.BasicPublish(exchange: "services", routingKey: routingKey, basicProperties: null, body: body);
```

Comment: On your server, you publish to a different exchange `databasechanges` than you declare `services`.

Comment: Forgot to change that while I was "anonymizing" the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are search on is the Topics exchange.

Beside my comment about you publish to a different exchange.

You exchange declare must be:

```
servicesChannel.ExchangeDeclare("services", type: "topic");
```

Read more and see code example here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-dotnet.html

Comment: I'll try this as soon as possible. Any idea why messages stop coming when I acknowledge it with `BasicAck()`?

Comment: My guess will be that either they are filtered out, or consumed by another client. Start the rabbitmq management and watch the queue depth, so you can see the message placed in the queue and somebody is consuming it.

Comment: Currently, in development, I have only one client, nobody else should be consuming them... But I'll check.